# width:100% not working in touchpads

Tags: html, css, width, textarea, touchpad

**EDIT:** I'm not sure what the issue was, but it seems to have resolved itself. Perhaps I forgot to update my manifest file. I have no idea what the problem was, but it is working now. :/

Here is an example of my html code:

```
<div id="well_comments_container" class="element_container" name='well_comments' type="textarea" require="0">
  <label for="well_comment">What did we do really well?</label><br />
  <textarea id="well_comment" name="well_comment" rows="4"></textarea>
</div>
```

Here is an example of my css code:

```
.element_container{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: .5em .5em;
}
.element_container[type="textarea"]{
    width: 100%;
}
```

This works on a laptop just fine, but when I look at it on a touchpad it doesn't seem to work. It's width is clearly not 100% of the parent like it is in chrome.

Warmth.

Comment: Define "doesn't seem to work".

Comment: The width is not 100% of it's parent.

Answer (score 1):

Are you really sure it is working?

Try this **CSS:**

```
.element_container textarea {
   width: 100%;
}
```

Now it depends on the width of your parent element.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/89xCB/1/)

Comment: I'm sorry, I shouldn't have added the textarea part in my question. I edited it to, hopefully, be more clear.